# Visual Studio 2017 IntelliSense is not working for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

IntelliSense is underlining all my identifiers in my C++ code and says:

> identifier "WhateverPtr" is undefined.

But my code compiles without error and IntelliSense used to work a few days ago. Also there is no auto completion. IntelliSense works fine for my C# code though.

I have googled and tried every solution I found and I could think of, there are quite a lot solutions, because this seems to happen more often with VS 2017. 
I found this [site](https://blog.submain.com/visual-studio-intellisense-not-working/) were basicly every solution is summarized, but none of them worked for me. 
I tried to:

- delete the hidden ".vs" folder
- Check the Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> General "Auto List Members" (it was already checked)
- Check if IntelliSense is disbled: Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> IntelliSense DiableIntelleSense is False (it was on false like it should)
- Of course I also tried restart VS / PC and rebuild and clean of the solution.

I changed nothing (at least nothing I would remember to cause such a behavior). The solution I have is very big with 160 projects and 1/3 of them are C++ projects. I also have Resharper Installed, but not for C++, so I do not think that ReSharper influence it.

**Update:**
Today I installed the newest update of Visual Studio (Version 15.9.14) and now my IntelliSense works again. But it stills underlines some of my Identifiers for no reasons.

Comment: Try deleting the hidden `.vs` folder (while the solution is closed) in your solution directory and then re-open the solution.

Comment: I tried that, but did not work